# Can't find kutil after installation of krb5-usr

Tags: debian, kerberos, packet

I need to merge keytab files and all tutorials mention `kutil`. But I can't find it:

```
root@nfsserver:/etc# kutil
bash: kutil: command not found
```

But krb5-usr is already installed:

```
krb5-user is already the newest version (1.18.3-6+deb11u1).
```

I have to actually merge the keys on two machines, both running Debian, one on Debian 10 and the other on Debian 11.

`klist` for example works; `/usr/bin/` contains only `kinit`, `klist` and `kmod`.
How do I get the `kutil` (or how do I merge the two keytab files at least)?

Furthermore I'm missing `read_kt` and `write_kt`..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `s/kutil/ktutil/`

Comment: @A.B Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: The command is probably not kutil but ktutil

Comment: Oh my god. Yes, sometimes copy & pasting helps